# python 3.4 button command using dictionary does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def But_Cmd(butcode):
global Button_select, frame1, b1, b2

def But_dic_lookup():    

    try:    
        Button_select[butcode]()
    except:  
        print('*** button select not found, butno= ', butcode)      
    return(But_dic_lookup)   
return

#===========================================================================
def Proc_button_100():
    print('Proc_button_ 100') 
    return 

def Proc_button_101():
    print('Proc_button_ 101')
    return 

def Proc_button_102():
    print('Proc_button_ 102')
    return 

def Proc_button_103():
    print('Proc_button_ 103')
    return 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------     
def Button_Dict():
    global Button_select

    Button_select = {
        100: Proc_button_100,
        101: Proc_button_101,
        102: Proc_button_102,
        103: Proc_button_103,
    } 

    return  

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
def List_Dic():
    for keys,values in Button_select.items():
        print(keys)
        print(values)
    return

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
#global Button_select, frame1, b1, b2

Button_Dict()    
List_Dic()

root.geometry("400x200+00+00") 

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.config(background= 'silver')
frame1.place(x = '00', y = '00', width = '400', height = '200' )
frame1.pack_propagate(0) 

b1 = Button(frame1, text='pusch1', command = But_Cmd('100'))
b1.config(background= 'orange')
b1.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)

b2 = Button(frame1, text='pusch2', command = But_Cmd('106'))
b2.config(background= 'light blue')
b2.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)

mainloop()
```

The python above is passing a code using button command. The code is using a dictionary switch to go to a function call. I use an 'entry' widget in the same way w/ no problem. The form and buttons display w/ no problem; the button command will not work. I also get 'too many connections' at bottom of GUI. I am using Wing IDE.

Comment: Indentation seems to be wrong after this `def But_Cmd(butcode)`. can you fix it, and double check other indentation. Without this its difficult to see the flow of your program.

Comment: How do you define "does not work"? Do you get an error? Does the program crash? Does the button do the wrong thing? What have you done to try and diagnose the problem?

Comment: You are correct! I changed the code. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You're using strings here:

```
command = But_Cmd('106')
```

But your actual dictionary is defined using integers:

```
Button_select = {
    100: Proc_button_100,  # etc.
```

So obviously the functions will never be found, because the keys you're using *aren't in the dictionary.* (In a similar vein, you've got a button code of 106 but no such function.)

My advice would be not to use the dictionary. At all. There is absolutely no benefit to using a function to get the desired function, rather than just using the desired function in the first place.

Also, give your objects meaningful names, not obscure numeric codes.